# image is shifted to the next element in recycler view

Tags: android, image, android-recyclerview

i am using recycler view,in that i m using an image to clear that particular message, that image is on a particular location only, so when the image is tapped, the message written in that location is erased but the image button is shifted to the next element.

this is my code

```
  messages.remove(location);
  mMessages.clear();
  mMessages.addAll(messages);
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  imageView.invalidate();
```

what should i do. the message is cleared but the image is shifted to the next element.

Comment: Please elaborate on the results you would like to achieve..

Comment: i want that when i remove the element. image should also be removed with it. it should not shifted downwards